# AWS IAM Policy - Restrict VPC Tenancy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

**Requirement:** To restrict IAM user from creating VPC with **dedicated tenancy**. IAM user should only be able to create VPC with **default tenancy**.

**IAM Policy Attached to IAM User:**

```
    {
        "Sid": "limitedTenancyVpc",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "ec2:CreateVpc",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:vpc/*",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAnyValue:StringNotLike": {
                "ec2:Tenancy": [
                    "default"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that for VPC **InstanceTenancy** is keyword to be used. I tried with it in condition, however it's not working. IAM user with this policy attached is able to create VPC with **dedicated tenancy**.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to restrict this as there is no condition associated with ec2:CreateVPC action. See the list of available [EC2 conditions keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html).

However, **ec2:tenancy** condition is available for ec2:runInstances. So you can instead deny requests to launch instances with dedicated tenancy as a guardrail.

There are 3 different tenancy types: default, dedicated and host. Deny requests if tenancy is set to either host or dedicated.

```
{
    "Sid": "limitedTenancyVpc",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
            "ec2:Tenancy": [
                "host", 
                "dedicated"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However this did not work. i am still able to create VPC with dedicated tenancy after adding above details in policy.

Comment: I understand your point, In AWS Management Console, we can only see default and dedicated while creating VPC.

Comment: My answer is used to deny if a user launches an instance with dedicated tenancy. However, you would like to prevent creating VPCs with dedicated tenancy.

Comment: yes.. i am looking for restriction while creating vpc.

Comment: it is unfortunately not possible. see my updated answer.

Comment: @PavanRao it seems possible that you are looking for something that would not help you even if it existed. This answer is correct, because VPC tenancy constrains the type of instance in only one direction, not the other -- a VPC with dedicated tenancy **requires** all instances to have dedicated tenancy, but *all* VPCs **allow** instances to have dedicated tenancy.  If you don't want to permit dedicated tenancy, restricting one type of VPC creation will not accomplish that objective.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot : Thank you for the comment. Yes,, I completely understand your point. I restricted the EC2 instances now. That will full-fill my requirement.